# Virtual includes with XAMPP

Tags: apache-virtualhost, xampp

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with XAMPP 7.3.7.1 for Linux. I have one acct. that uses HTML and so I use `<!--#include virtual="/includes/css.html" -->` for my includes. The problem is when I bring up the virtual host, it doesn't display any of the includes. I already have other sites that work but they use PHP. Any idea on how to fix this?

If this has already been solved, point the way.

Answer (score 0):

The path was wrong. It should have been `include_path = ".:includes"`